# Matrix completion with proximal gradient method

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, proximal-operators

I am trying to solve the matrix completion problem with proximal gradient method: $$\min_{||X||_* \leq \theta} \frac{1}{2}\sum_{(i, j) \in \Omega} (X_{ij} - M_{ij})^2$$ or in terms of the projection operator: $$\min_{||X||_* \leq \theta} \frac{1}{2} ||P_\Omega(X) - P_\Omega(M)||_F^2$$

Now, I know how to solve $$\min_{||X||_* \leq \theta} \frac{1}{2} ||X-Y||_F^2$$ since that is just $X = U D^* V^T$ where $Y = UDV^T$ and $D^* = diag(d^*)$ and $D = diag(d)$ where $d^*$ is the solution to $$\min_{||x||_1 \leq \theta} ||x-d||^2$$. Can someone point in the right direction on how to apply this to solve the matrix completion problem using proximal gradient method?

Comment: Are you talking about proximal gradient method applied to the function $\frac{1}{2} \|P_{\Omega}(X) - P_{\Omega}(M)\|_{\mathrm{F}}^2 + \delta_{\|X\|_{\star} \leq \theta}(X)$, where $\delta$ is the indicator function?

Comment: @VHarisop Yes what is the proximal gradient method iteration look like?

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}$ So I just realized that $$\argmin_{X} \frac{1}{2}||X-Y||_F^2 + \delta_{\{||X||_* < \theta\}} = prox_{\delta_{\{||X||_* < \theta\}}}(Y)$$ not sure how this helps with proximal gradient iteration step

Comment: In your case, the proximal gradient iteration would be $X_{k+1} = \mathrm{Proj}_{\|X\|_{\star} \leq \theta}(X_{k} - \eta_k \nabla f(X_{k}))$, where $X_{k}$ is the current iterate, $\mathrm{Proj}$ is the projection operator, $f(X_{k})$ is the cost function $\|P_{\Omega}(X_k) - P_{\Omega}(M)\|_{\mathrm{F}}^2$, and $\eta_k$ is an appropriately chosen stepsize.

Comment: To compute the gradient $\nabla f(X_k)$, you can make use of the chain rule since the function is the composition of the squared norm with a linear mapping.

Comment: The gradient is $P_\Omega(X_k) - P_\Omega(M)$ and you mean proximal operator of the indicator function instead of projection operator right?

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\prox}{prox}$ So it would be $$X^{k+1} = \prox_{\alpha_k \delta_{\{  ||X||_* < \theta \}}}(X^k - \alpha_k \nabla f(X^k))$$

Comment: The proximal operator of an indicator function is the projection operator.